# Showing modal-box morethan 1 on a page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

<< Referring to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952407/how-can-i-pass-the-chosen-value-on-a-modal-box-to-php/11953436#11953436) >>

I want to make several modal-box on a page:

```
<script>
var grid_modal_options = {
    height: 'auto',
    width: '80%',
    modal: true
};
function showProducts1ModalBox() {
    $("#products1_modal_box").dialog(grid_modal_options);
    $("#products1_modal_box").parent().appendTo('form:first');
}
function showProducts2ModalBox() {
    $("#products2_modal_box").dialog(grid_modal_options);
    $("#products2_modal_box").parent().appendTo('form:first');
}
function showProducts3ModalBox() {
    $("#products3_modal_box").dialog(grid_modal_options);
    $("#products3_modal_box").parent().appendTo('form:first');
}
</script>

<div id="products1_modal_box" title="Products" style="display: none;">
  <div class="in">
    <div class="grid-12-12">
      <form id="products1_modal_box_form" action="#" method="post">
    <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
              <th>Product</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <!-- Query for read mysql goes here (I skipped this line because it's not the main thing I'm gonna ask since it's run well) /-->
          <tbody>
          <?php
            //read the results
            while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {                
              print "<tr>";
              print "  <td><a href=\"javascript:;\" onclick=\"$('#products1_id_textbox').val('".$fetch[0]."');$('#products1_modal_box').dialog('close');\">Choose</a></td>";
              print "  <td>" . $fetch[0] . "</td>"; //$fetch[0] == Product ID
              print "</tr>";
            }
          ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="products2_modal_box" title="Products" style="display: none;">
  <!-- 
    The rest goes here (the same with "products1_modal_box") 
    except: 
    print "  <td><a href=\"javascript:;\" onclick=\"$('#products2_id_textbox').val('".$fetch[0]."');$('#products2_modal_box').dialog('close');\">Choose</a></td>";
  /-->
</div>

<div id="products3_modal_box" title="Products" style="display: none;">
  <!-- 
    The rest goes here (the same with "products1_modal_box") 
    except: 
    print "  <td><a href=\"javascript:;\" onclick=\"$('#products3_id_textbox').val('".$fetch[0]."');$('#products3_modal_box').dialog('close');\">Choose</a></td>";
  /-->
</div>
```

And:

```
<input type='text' id='products1_id_textbox' name='products1_id_textbox' />
<a href='#' onclick='showProducts1ModalBox(); return false;'>Choose products 1</a>

<input type='text' id='products2_id_textbox' name='products2_id_textbox' />
<a href='#' onclick='showProducts2ModalBox(); return false;'>Choose products 2</a>

<input type='text' id='products3_id_textbox' name='products3_id_textbox' />
<a href='#' onclick='showProducts3ModalBox(); return false;'>Choose products 3</a>
```

Why this doesn't work? When I removed the div "products2_modal_box" and "products3_modal_box", the modal-box for div "products1_modal_box" appear, but when I tried to get back all of them, each modal-box doesn't appear while I clicked the link. What's wrong with the code? Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't technically answer your question, but I use jQuery Reveal for modals on my site. Seems a lot easier than what you're trying to do. Here's the source: http://www.zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin

It's really easy to set up, and you can have multiple modals per page, and can trigger them with an event (such as a click) or dynamically with jquery.

Hope this helps!