# JQuery Checked Selector on a modal-box and return it on the page

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-selectors, checkbox, checked

What I want to do is, return the value checked on each checkbox on a modal-box to a text-box. This question is quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952407/how-can-i-pass-the-chosen-value-on-a-modal-box-to-php), but the aim of the question is different. So please take a look both of them. :)

I've the code to initialize the modal-box:

```
<script>
var grid_modal_options = {
    height: 'auto',
    width: '80%',
    modal: true
};
function showProductsModalBox() {
    $("#products_modal_box").dialog(grid_modal_options);
    $("#products_modal_box").parent().appendTo('form:first');
}
</script>

<div id="products_modal_box" title="Products" style="display: none;">
  <div class="in">
    <div class="grid-12-12">
      <form id="products_modal_box_form" action="#" method="post">
        <a href=\"javascript:;\" onclick=\"$('#products_id_textbox').val(\"input[name='checkedID[]']:checked\");$('#products_modal_box').dialog('close')();\">Submit</a>
         <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
              <th>Product</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <!-- Query for read mysql goes here (I skipped this line because it's not the main thing I'm gonna ask since it's run well) /-->
          <tbody>
          <?php
            //read the results
            while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {                
              print "<tr>";
              print "  <td><input type='checkbox' name='checkedID' value='" . $fetch[0] . "' /></td>"; //--> How to get the value of $fetch[0], collect it and return to a textbox?
              print "  <td>" . $fetch[0] . "</td>"; //$fetch[0] == Product ID
              print "</tr>";
            }
          ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you see above, I am trying to use [pseudo-selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/checked) function: `input[name='checkedID[]']:checked` but failed to return the value. Or there is something I missed for the code?

And here is the textbox for return the value checked on the modal-box:

```
<input type='text' id='products_id_textbox' name='products_id_textbox' />
<a href='#' onclick='showProductsModalBox(); return false;'>Choose products</a>
```

The code able is to show the modal-box. But how to return the "Product" chosen from each textbox by the user to the textbox `products_id_textbox`? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem solved with this code:

```
<script>
$("input#checkedID").change(function () {
  var str = "";
  $("input:[name='checkedID[]']:checked").each(function () {
        str += $(this).val() + ", ";
  });
  $("input#products_id_textbox").val(str);
})
.trigger('change');
</script>
```

and a modification on the button that just for closing the modal-box:

```
<a href=\"javascript:;\" onclick=\"$('#products_modal_box').dialog('close')();\">Submit</a>
```

That function called  **[:checked Selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)**.

Thank you very much and hope helps... :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are outputting from php is checkedID not checkedID[]
Change

```
print "  <td><input type='checkbox' name='checkedID' value='" . $fetch[0] . "' /></td>";
```

to

```
print "  <td><input type='checkbox' name='checkedID[]' value='" . $fetch[0] . "' /></td>";
```

Comment: There seems to be errors on onclick, try wrinting a function for clarity. You will probably have to use $.each on $('input[name="checkedID[]"]:checked') to get the values

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
    myCheckbox is a class which you need to assign your checkboxes..

    var checkboxValues = $('.myCheckbox:checked').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();


Then you can assign that values into your textbox....

$('#products_id_textbox').val(checkboxValues);
```

Hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

Your selector should look like,

```
$("input[name='checkedID[]']:checked")
```

It gives you all the checkbox with name "checkedID[]" is checked. you have to loop it to get all the values.

Hope this helps !